# Logout automatically use after session expire in yii2

Tags: yii2

How and where can i write code to redirect to login page after the session expires in Yii2.0 ?

```
 // if (!Yii::$app->controller->id == 'site') {
    //     $session = Yii::$app->session;
    //     if (!$session->isActive) {
    //         $model = new LoginForm();
    //         return $this->goHome();
    //     }        
    // }
```

i tried to do this in the base controller.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you never know when user session is expire , but you can force users to login before using some actions :

```
 public function behaviors()
{
    return [
        'access' => [
            'class' => AccessControl::className(),
            'rules' => [

                [
                    'actions' => ['youraction'],
                    'allow' => true,
                    'roles' => ['@'], // you can use matchCallback to create  more powerful  check 
                ],
            ],
        ], 

    ];
}
```

dont forget to  add use yii\filters\AccessControl;